# Facebook crops open graph image in to a square

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a custom open graph story to Facebook but I'm having some trouble getting the `og:image` to show properly. I'm using a 1200*630 sized image as recommended [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/#properties) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images) but on my timeline it gets cropped in to a square from the left edge of the image. It also shows as a square in the story preview though this time it's cropped from the center.

How can I get the image to show in the correct aspect ratio and size? Is it just the test environment to blame or do I need to add something on my server side? I've already tried to use the meta tags `width` and `height` with no success.

Currently the tag looks like this:

`<meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.linktomyimage/1200x630pixels.png" />`

Comment: can you add some code to your question?

Comment: There's really not much special code on our end. I added the og:image property tag though if that has any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When viewing the story from the feed is the image displayed correctly?  This is the case for me.

Comment: @Starcade I reached out to a contact at Facebook.  He thinks this is a bug on their end and he is filing it to be fixed.

Comment: Facebook has changed their buttons recently. Now more important is your og:type. What og:type you use matters, you probably want to use article but at the very least use the developer tool to make sure the rest of your open graph meta data tags are correct and choose the proper og:type.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: Stuff changed: check http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

> Open Graph Stories Images appear in a square format. Image ratios for
>   these apps should be 600 x 600 px.

from [Facebook sharing best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have your image at an 1.91:1 aspect ratio. Facebook also notes that images for game app stories appear square, but I'm not sure from your information above if that applies to your situation. GL

Answer (score -1):

It shows the 1200 X 630 image on retina screens only.

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding explanation.