# Facebook, opengraph, how do they crop?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a website, with a simple 500x500 image listed appropriately in the `<meta property="og:image" content="image.jpg" />`

Facebook will sometimes crop and use the top of the image, the middle or in some cases the bottom to get it's required aspect ratio out of it. Is there anything I can do to control this? Or better yet, get it to take the entire square image in like every other social networking site does?

`In my findings if your image is not 600x315 1200x630 or other 40:21 ratio facebook has a three step algorithm for determining what to crop as outlined below.`

> FINDINGS:
>
> First Priortiy: Face detection. Detects center point of faces. If
>   multiple faces determines the ones that are closest together and bases
>   the crop on that.
>
> Second Priority: Some sort of contrast detection: Detail > Colors >
>   Contrast. So if you had a picture of a face on the top of an image and
>   the rest of the image was blurred out because the picture was taken
>   with an extremely low aperture. Then, if you have a lot of colors in a
>   certain part of an image it would favor that and then if there was a
>   really dark image that had a bright white watermark in the bottom
>   right hand corner it would favor that.
>
> Third Priority: This is more of a default, if the above two don't
>   work, it defaults to a center crop.

Answer (score 0):

After researching on facebook I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#images) article about what image sizes and aspect ratio are recommended by facebook.

I haven't tried this personally, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537676/facebook-crops-open-graph-image-in-to-a-square) StackOverflow question says they have already tried what facebook recommended in the article.

I will try implementing image sizes recommended on facebook and will edit the answer appropriately.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I came across those two links you mentioned and a ton of others prior to posting. I was really hoping I'd be able to make one image work with all the social networks, but I ended up biting the bullet and changing my application to output images specifically for Facebook. I updated my question with my findings.