# Facebook Graph 2.9 Have Square Images

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook API generated feed on my website that shows the last post of whatever I posted on Facebook. In this case, it was an article I wrote about Launtua Island. When I visit my Facebook page, the image looks like this:

[image: Launtua Island rectangular picture]

But when I visited my website, the image looks like this:

[image: Launtua Island squre picture]

It appears Facebook is cropping my image, but I don't know how to prevent it. This is the code I'm using:

```
$feed = 'Feed Id';
$a_token = 'Secret Access Token';
$maximum = 1;

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$feed}/feed?access_token={$a_token}&limit={$maximum}";

$response = file_get_contents($url); 

$facebookString = $response;
$facebookArray = json_decode($facebookString);
$array = array();
foreach ( $facebookArray->data as $each ) {
    $each->message = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/.*) ?$/", "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>", $each->message);
    $row = array();
    $response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$each->id}/attachments?access_token={$a_token}");

    $image = json_decode($response);
    $src = $image->data[0]->media->image->src;
    if ($src == '') {
        $src = $image->data[0]->subattachments->data[0]->media->image->src;
    }

    $row['post'] = $each->message;
    $row['image'] =  $src;
    $row['time'] = strtotime($each->created_time);
    $array[] = $row;
}
$string = "";
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    $string .= "<div class='post'>";
    if ($entry['image'] != '') {
        $string .= "<img src='{$entry['image']}'>";
    }
    $string .= "<p>" . $entry['post'] . "</p>";
    $string .= "</div>";
}
echo $string;
```

There is a lot of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456823/getting-a-cropped-image-or-square-image-back-for-the-album-cover-photo-in-facebo) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537676/facebook-crops-open-graph-image-in-to-a-square) to my problem, but I'm not sure this is the same issue (not asking for image when making request) or a different one.

It would be great if Facebook stopped changing their API all the time!

Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, this cannot be changed.

Comment: @Axalix I hoped that wasn't the case. It looks awful. But I'm sure there's some reason for it.

Comment: Try the `full_picture` field.

Comment: @CBroe Can you expand on that? Do you mean when I generate the access token?

Comment: No, I mean the field of the post object.